# Род глагола при использовании с названием произведения

Tags: синтаксис

Допустим, у нас есть некое произведение - книга, фильм, песня и т. д. И упоминаем мы это произведение непосредственно по названию, причем само название может иметь определенный род. Например, фильм "Матрица".

Вопрос - какого рода должен быть глагол относительно этого произведения? Род необходимо выбирать исходя из названия ("Матрица", значит, "показала"), или рода произведения (фильм, значит, "показал")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я девушка простая, примеры заимствую у Сержа:

*Журнал «Итоги» уже продан. — «Итоги» уже проданы; Автомашина «Жигули» была похищена с охраняемой стоянки. — «Жигули» была похищены с охраняемой стоянки.*

Вам непременно правило надо?

---

[**«Итоги» попытались** понять](http://www.itogi.ru/zdorovie/2014/8/198341.html),

> что на самом деле имел в виду известный врач, а также что за
>   бухгалтерия кроется за всей этой историей болезни.

**[«Итоги» выяснили,](http://www.itogi.ru/)**

> что на самом деле имел в виду известный врач, а также то, что за
>   бухгалтерия кроется за всей этой историей болезни.

[**«Матрица», вышедшая**](https://www.mirf.ru/kino/matrix-kak-sozdavalsya-film)

> в прокат семнадцать лет назад, 31 марта 1999 года, **произвела**
>   настоящий фурор.
>
> ---
>
> Смертность космических аппаратов в его окрестностях достигает 70%.
>   Зем­ные аппараты барахлят в этих местах, как [**глохнут** на дороге
>   **«Жигули»**](http://podarok-noviy-god2017.ru/68670.html)...

Answer (score 0):

В примерах, которые Вы приводите, родовое слово является определяемым словом (подлежащим), а название - несогласованным приложением. В подобных случаях сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим, а не с приложением.

Ср. примеры: **Журнал** «Итоги» уже продан. — **Журнал** продан; **Автомашина** «Жигули» была похищена с охраняемой стоянки.  — **Автомашина** была похищена с охраняемой стоянки.

[Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ
 М.: ЧеРо, 1999](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_03)